# Under what conditions do the angle bisectors of a triangle make $120^\circ$ angles at the incenter?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I haven't messed around with geometry in a while.
[image]

> What criteria does this triangle need to meet so you can state that the incircle angles $\alpha,\beta, \gamma $ here equal 120º?  Do any of the sides have to have same length? Right angles? Anything?

I tried using the law of cosines, but that doesn't seem very fruitful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if the incircle angles are each $120^{\circ}$ then this is the Torricelli point as well as the incenter. That may give you more information.

Comment: Toricelli/Fermat points are made by joining each vertex to a  vertically opposite erected equilateral triangle vertex. Physically it is a triple point made by a  minimal soap film through $(A,B,C)$ at $120^{\circ}$. To coincide with in-center $ABC$ should be equilateral itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\alpha +A/2 + C/2 = 180$, it follows that $A/2+C/2=60$, or $A+C=120$. Thus, $B=60$. Similarly, $A=60$ and $B=60$. So $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.